# How can I remove the Add Product (s) in woocommerce order admin page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to customize my "Add new" order page.
I want to remove the "Add product(s)" line along with other lines on that row.

[image]

would love to have some explanation of how to find the relevant data for filtering the buttons out.

I have searched the forum and found that adding a similar filter might be the option.

```
// remove Order Notes from checkout field in Woocommerce
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'alter_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
function alter_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the filter you posted?

Comment: But obviously with the add products button instead of order comments?

Comment: Looking at their documentation, that filter is only for whats inside the white box pretty much. Can't you just set `display:none` for the buttons you don't want?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I know that filter is not for my use but rather for the order details. Was wondering if you could do something similar. In which css would I add the display:none?

Comment: I tried adding

.button.button.add-order-item{ display: none !important; };

to the admin.css within the woocommerce/assets/css 

It didnt work